# Reset git autocomplete cache?

Tags: git, autocomplete

I used to have a partially working version of git autocomplete from https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/completion. I've been messing around and now it is completely broken.

Originally the autocomplete could complete all the git commands and branches; however, it wouldn't show any aliases I had. I tried to fix this by fiddling around a lot. I ended up then breaking it so it wouldn't autocomplete aliases or branches (`git checkout <TAB><TAB>` would only show HEAD when there were plenty of branches). Then I ended up really breaking it...

What might have broke it is I believe I ran `__git_complete map git_map` where `map` was a git alias I had made in my gitconfig file. Now when I try to do a git autocomplete it only shows a weird list of options shown below. These are a few commands like `rebase`, aliases I have across my system and global files like `s` (system) and `map` (global), and other things I'm not completely sure of.

---

`git <TAB> <TAB>`

```
a                     cm                    master 
aa                    d                     mergetool 
ac                    filter-branch         p4 
acm                   gui                   rebase 
addnw                 imap-send             request-pull 
alias                 instaweb              s 
au                    l                     send-email 
bisect                lg                    spull 
c                     ll                    spush 
ca                    llg                   stash 
citool                map                   submodule 
clang-format-mp-3.8   mapall                subtree 
clang-format-mp-3.9   mapblame              svn
```

---

Is there a way to just reset all the autocomplete options. Restarting my system, redownloading the completion script all did nothing. It seems the tool still functions, but I've broken what commands it has available to itself. I'd be plenty content to get back to the original state, if there is some kind of cache that could be reset for the autocomplete tools.

I'm on OSX 10.10.5, GNU bash version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14), git version 2.14.1.

---

**EDIT**: what I think I did that really flubbed things up is `__git_complete git __git_main`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had a pathing issue, and git that came with Xcode command line tools was being used for some options and the official git release was being used in other places. I forget exactly what, but the git that Apple ships out is lacking features and I replaced it with the official version when it was 2.14.1.

I ended up downloading the latest nightly version of git (git version 2.14.1.536.g6867272d5) from the official github repo and building. I figured this version of git had to work properly with their autocomplete script (perhaps the apple version one fails). I then updated my paths so that "~/bin" (where the git is installed by default from the make file) takes precedent, by making it the first line in `/etc/paths`.

Now my git autocomplete correctly finds commands, branches and aliases. I know some answers out there in other tangentially related question found resolution with moving away from Apple's version of bash, but I don't think that is necessary.

A strange aside: I also have no recollection of making a systemwide gitconfig (/User/NAME/etc/.gitconfig) file (which had aliases I was unfamiliar appearing in that list above with like `a`, `s`, `aa`, etc. and now that I redid everything it has disappeared.